# Order/Sorting of Iterate Field Values (ModelBuilder)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, loop

I am using [Iterate Field Values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Examples_of_using_iterators_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001n000000/ESRI_SECTION1_33EDB1C8829F4CF4BBD5DABAA3ED34DD/) to Iterate my Model through a list of Strings (DBF-File). However, the Field Values-Iterator will always sort my Field by alphabet (ascending). It does not matter how the rows in the *.dbf are ordered.

**Is it possible to run the model using a different sorting method?**

Example of dbf-file:

```
house
mill
water
tree
cafe
garden
```

.. will run as

```
cafe  
garden  
house
mill
tree
water
```

I would like to run the Model by the first sequence of strings, not the second one. Is this possible? 
I tried adding a second column with numbers from 1 up to x, but the Iterator ignores this field.

Comment: I think maybe that it iterates based on OBJECTID.  Do the object ID's correspond to alphabetical order? If this is the case, I may have a solution.

Comment: Can you expand more what the end need is for the sorted list?

Comment: Thank you Tangnar and artwork21. The iterator will always sort ascending by the field I am iterating over. It does not matter how the dbf or shapefile is ordered, or whether I add another Field with ascending numbers in correct order.

Comment: The need for the ordered list the following: a group of students will use my model to process a list of strings. The strings are ordered by importance. Because the students will not be able to process all strings from the list during the course, I would like the model to start with the most important, descending to less important strings. This does not match with alphabetic numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have discovered a quirk of the Iterator. There is no indication in the help file that the iterator sorts the field. So the only way I can think of doing this is to add a field to your dataset and you number the rows in the order you wish to visit them. You then iterate over that field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I am sorry for my late reply.
@Hornbydd: I think you're right and there is no way around the Auto-Sort function. But how do I Iterate over the new field with correct numbers [Field 1] and read [Field 2] into inline variable substitution (%variableString%). Is this possible?